# 2 SELECT in 1 query results in 4 results when expecting 2 results

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql database: accounts and users

Accounts looks like this:[image]

Users Looks like this:[image]

I want to select accountid and userid from both tables and get results like so:

```
accountid || userid
7            22
29           44
```

I don't understand why it gives me 4 results like so:

[image]

Comment: Well, we do not know about the same names. Without the ON-condition every row in table1 is joined with every row in table2.

Comment: You're right ! I mixed up with "NATURAL" join.. I'm going to delete it to avoid mistakes for others

Comment: provide your db schema, and condition why  `accountid =7` is linked to `userid=22` but not 44?

Comment: I rewrote my question to make it more understandable, sorry for the poor question

Comment: I don't understand why the FK of the accounts table would be anything other than the PK of the user table !?!

Comment: Matching with name.. Not by ID.. Too fragile and is there a unique constraint on "name" column ? Why this choice ?

Comment: I haven't used a PK or an FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshots you have tables linked by `username` which is very poor db design.

So you should definitely change your schema and use `user.id` to link your tables.

But so far your query is:

```
SELECT accounts.accountid, users.userid
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN users
ON accounts.username=users.username
```

Comment: This syntax does what i need and i have taken into account what you mentioned about by FK. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We do not know exactly about our table structure, but you are definitly missing the ON-part on the join

SELECT accounts.accountid, users.userid
  FROM accounts
  INNER JOIN users ON users.userid = accounts.userid

Or whatever you want to compare

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the 'ON' part of the syntax, give this a try:

```
SELECT accounts.accountid, users.userid
FROM accounts
INNER JOIN users
ON accounts.userid=users.userid;
```

Make sure you have 'userid' in your 'accounts' table for this to work, this tells the query to join the 'userid' in both tables and should prevent any duplicate rows.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why u not getting the answer but u should have know the one point that u have username common in both the table so if u join the table with the help of username of both the table u defintely get result like

```
select accountid,userid from Accounts inner join Users where Accounts.username=Users.username;
```